# Laravel not storing session data in Redis

Tags: session, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.4, predis

I just decided to switch to **Redis** to store my session and cache data. But Laravel seems to use local file storage itself.

I have installed the **predis** composer dependency and have changed the config to:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=secret
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

also in the `config/session.php` file, I have used `'connection' => 'redis'`. Still, it seems to store all my login cookies and session data in the `storage/framework/session`

What do I need to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might be using config caching. You should run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

to flush your config data.